# Do $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

There is a property that I've been told by my quantum physics teacher that states:

> Being $A$ and $B$ Hermitian, if $AB-BA=0$ then $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.

I do not even know how to start the proof for this. I believe my teacher but I just want to understand where that comes from. Would the property also be valid for eigenvectors? I mean, if $AB-BA=0$, would not only the eigenvalues but also the eigenvectors be the same for both $A$ and $B$?

Comment: It is true that they have the same eigenvectors (as long as neither has repeated eigenvalues). Not eigenvalues, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this were true, then $A$ and $A^2$ would have the same eigenvalues, for any Hermitian matrix $A$. SO it is false.

It is true that if both products $AB$ and $BA$ are defined, then $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues with the same multiplities.

Comment: Why do you say that $A$ and $A^2$ would have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: $AA^2- A^2A= A^3-A^3 = 0$.

Comment: +1 how do you prove your last assertion? :-)

Comment: @Ant $AB=BA$ so both products represent the same matrix, so the eigenvalues have to be the same (as the matrix is the same)

Comment: @M.S. Well yeah, but that's just saying that $A$ and $A$ have the same eigenvalues (clearly! :P) but that is not what Chris wrote; he said if $AB$ and $BA$ are both defined (not necessarily equal) then they have the same non-zero eigenvalues

Comment: @Ant I assumed that he referred to the case in which $A$ and $B$ accomplished the condition I wrote in my question, I don't know if he meant anything else

Comment: @M.S.: My last claim does not require $A$ and $B$ to be Hermitian. I included it because I thought that the false claim might be a mixed up version of this statement.

Comment: @M.S. I see :-) But in that case it is obvious, since if any two objects $x$ and $y$ are equal ($x = y$) then they share any possible property (clearly, since they are the same object)

Comment: @ChrisGodsil And what about the eigenvectors? If the statement in my question is true (both are Hermitian and their products commute), are their eigenvectors the same?

Comment: @M.S.: If Hermitian matrices commute then they have the same eigenvectors (more precisely, they can be simultaneously diagonalized). Their eigenvalues will not be the same unless the matrices are equal.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=[3]$ and $B=[2]$ then both $A$ and $B$ has different eigenvalues but $AB-BA=0$.